# Wordwrap in AlivePDF

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, air, alivepdf

when i am showing some text it is going in 1 line only   thats why
whole  text is not visible in pdf.
if txt are more it should take automatically next line.
please see code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
layout="horizontal" >
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
           import org.alivepdf.pdf.PDF;
            import org.alivepdf.saving.Method;
            import org.alivepdf.fonts.*;
            import org.alivepdf.pages.Page;
             import org.alivepdf.display.Display;
             import org.alivepdf.layout.*;

    [Bindable] private var message:String;
   private var pdf:PDF;
            private var file:File;
            private function submitData():void {
            message+='The Text Value is ' + t1.text + ' The second
text value is' + t2.text +
                        'it is testing message it is testing message it is
testing message '+
                        'The Text Value is ' + t1.text + ' The second text value
is' + t2.text+
                        'it is testing message it is testing message it is
testing message ';
            }

             public function generate ():void
             {
                submitData();

             var pdf:PDF = new PDF( Orientation.PORTRAIT, Unit.MM,
Size.A4 );
                 pdf.setDisplayMode( Display.FULL_PAGE,
Layout.SINGLE_PAGE );
                var newPage:Page = new Page (Orientation.PORTRAIT,
Unit.MM, Size.A4 );
                pdf.addPage( newPage );
                //pdf.setFont(IFont,12);
                pdf.addText(message,5,15);
                pdf.addPage();
                var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
                file =
File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("testPage.pdf");
                fs.open( file, FileMode.WRITE);
                var bytes:ByteArray = pdf.save(Method.LOCAL);
                                 fs.writeBytes(bytes);
                fs.close();
             }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:TextInput id="t1"  text="txt111" />
    <mx:TextInput id="t2"  text="txt222"/>
   <mx:Button click="generate()" label="Generate PDF"
horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>

    </mx:WindowedApplication>
```

is any solution to show text in pdf, can we give font size also to our
text ?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `addText` doesn't wrap. Use `writeText` method instead.

From the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/alivepdf/wiki/APINotes):

> The `addText()` method will put out text at a given coordinate. **No word wrapping is done**.

The linked page has code samples for both methods.